# linq: how to check if the value of one attribute exists

Tags: c#, .net, linq, if-statement

if statement to check the value of an attribute doesn't work.

`if (element.Elements(ns + "list").Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "myProject") != null)`

Is there other way to check if the value of an attribute exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `firstordefault`

```
var element = element.Elements(ns + "list").Where(x => x.Attribute == "myProject");

// return if null 


if(element == null) return;



// do your stuff
```

Sorry for messy indentation as I'm typing on mobile :)